# How can i set image view in other class resource?

Tags: android

I'm new in android and want to write simple this class:

```
public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    public ImageView displayedImage;
    public TextView textTitle;
    public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        textTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_header);
        displayedImage=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    }
}
```

Now want to change up image resource for that purpose write this code:

```
((RecyclerViewHolders)holder).displayedImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.beh);
```

But that not work,how can i solve that problem?thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image for your ImageView like this, if you have an image called `my_image` in your drawable folder:

```
displayedImage=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
displayedImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
```